# UWP Unsupported API

Tags: c#, c++, api, dll, uwp

I am trying to publish my UWP application to the Windows Store but I'm encountering a problem with unsupported APIs. The APIs in question are opus.dll (Opus) and libsodium.dll (NaCl).

I know this means that I need to find universal versions of these and somehow make the package I'm using (Discord.Net) reference them instead of the original ones, but does anybody know where to find universal versions? I can't seem to find any besides the original C ones.

For reference, this is the error:

> - API crypto_secretbox_easy in libsodium.dll is not supported for this application type. Discord.Net.WebSocket.dll calls this API.
> - API crypto_secretbox_open_easy in libsodium.dll is not supported for this application type. Discord.Net.WebSocket.dll calls this API.
> - API opus_decode in opus.dll is not supported for this application type. Discord.Net.WebSocket.dll calls this API.
> - API opus_decoder_create in opus.dll is not supported for this application type. Discord.Net.WebSocket.dll calls this API.
> - API opus_decoder_destroy in opus.dll is not supported for this application type. Discord.Net.WebSocket.dll calls this API.
> - API opus_encode in opus.dll is not supported for this application type. Discord.Net.WebSocket.dll calls this API.
> - API opus_encoder_create in opus.dll is not supported for this application type. Discord.Net.WebSocket.dll calls this API.
> - API opus_encoder_ctl in opus.dll is not supported for this application type. Discord.Net.WebSocket.dll calls this API.
> - API opus_encoder_destroy in opus.dll is not supported for this application type. Discord.Net.WebSocket.dll calls this API.

Comment: Do you know who maintains the Discord library? You can ask them if they have a UWP version available. Alternatively, if you know who owns opus and libsodium you could ask them for UWP-compliant versions and then bundle them with your package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't publish those libraries to the Store, at least not as the dlls are built. You need to make (but more specifically compile) your own dll files with the proper settings for Windows Store release.